# ¿como obtener valor de un span dentro de un foreach php con javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Hola estoy realizado una consulta con php y foreach traigo el id del usuario y lo muestro en un `span` ahora quisiera ese valor de id capturarlo con javascript, para ello coloque un boton que al hacer click debe capturar el valor del id y con lo que llevo hecho hasta ahora solo me muestra siempre un mismo valor de id.

```
   <div class="container-list--profesores">
                    <?php
                    foreach ($rows as $data) {
                    ?>
                        <div class="card-container">
                            <span class="pro" id="idPerfil"><?php echo $data['id_usuarios'] ?></span>
                            <div class="buttons">
                                <button class="primary edit" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#editarPerfil">
                                    Editar Perfil
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>
```

y en javascript

```
$(".edit").on("click", function () {
  const id = document.getElementById("idPerfil").textContent;
  console.log(id);
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: base_url + "functions/consultar.php",
    data: {
      id: id,
    },
    cache: false,
    success: function (result) {
     console.log(result);
      const resp = JSON.parse(result);
    },
  });
});
```

Como deberia proceder en este caso.

Comment: Los ID no deben repetirse en HTML.  Tu getElementById solo captura el primero de ellos, no el que pretendes.

Comment: gracias ya veo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los `id` no deben repetirse en HTML. Tu `getElementById('id_perfil')` solo captura el primero de ellos, no el que pretendes.

En su lugar puedes usar las clases y los métodos de posicionamiento de jquery para ello, basándote en el botón que pulsas, sustituyendo esta línea:

```
const id = document.getElementById("idPerfil").textContent;
```

por esta otra:

```
const id = $(this).closest('.card-container').find('.pro').text();
```

donde desde el botón que es pulsado (representado por `$(this)`), buscamos su ancestro mas cercano con la clase `.card-container` y una vez lo encontramos buscamos su descendiente con la clase `.pro` más cercano también, y de el sacamos su texto mediante `text()`.

**Nota**: Por otro lado, si usamos **jquery**, hemos de intentar no mezclar funciones de **javascript** que ya tienen su equivalencia con métodos de *jquery*, pues una gran parte de las funciones de  javascript más comunes, como el `getElementById('idPerfil')`, tienen su correspondencia en jquery, que en este caso seria `$('#idPerfil')`, aunque seguiría sin funcionarte en tu caso por lo explicado antes.

Comment: Gracias me ah servido mucho y mas la explicación por si me vuelvo a topar con esta situación a futuro.

Comment: Me alegro. Es muy útil saber la estructura del HTML para resolver este tipo de situaciones, y aprenderse bien métodos de posicionamiento y búsqueda como los que te he mostrado en esta respuesta. Aún así hay muchos más, los encontrarás en [este enlace](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/) a su documentación.